# Using SQL, how do I convert a comma separated list to be used with the IN command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-like, sql-in

Currently I have a table that has a user_type column and will only show the row if the user matches that user_type. I want to make it so there can be multiple user_types set without duplicating the data and without creating another table. I thought that I could convert the column from an int to varchar and have it be a comma separated list of user type IDs.

So far it has been working great. That is as long as I know what the user_type is beforehand because then I can specifically use that when checking if I should display to the user:

```
SELECT *
FROM perm
WHERE user_type='50'
    OR user_type LIKE '50,%'
    OR user_type LIKE '%,50,%'
    OR user_type LIKE '%,50'
```

The issue comes when I am trying to join tables on the value. When I tried using `IN`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM perm p
JOIN [user] u ON u.type IN (p.user_type)
```

I get the error: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '50,40,30' to data type int.` So I decided I would go back to the `LIKE` method which I have been using above:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM perm p
JOIN [user] u ON (
    u.type LIKE p.user_type
    OR u.type LIKE (p.user_type + ',%')
    OR u.type LIKE ('%,' + p.user_type + ',%')
    OR u.type LIKE ('%,' + p.user_type)
)
```

This only returns results that have one user type value only. Is there a way to convert a comma separated list to be used with the `IN` command? Or is there any way to make a dynamic `LIKE` argument?

Comment: `I thought that I could convert the column from an int to varchar and have it be a comma separated list of user type IDs`  This is a very bad idea.  Create another table. Maintaining a comma separated list is an huge hassle.

Comment: What @paqogomez said. As you've found it's difficult to "unroll" the data if done this way. Additionally it negates the DB's strengths (its relational ability).

Comment: As was already said, this is a bad idea. Anyway, change your `JOIN` condition with: `ON p.user_type LIKE '%,' + u.type + ',%'`

Comment: Indeed. However, in my case I wouldn't need to maintain this comma separated list. Once the user type is set, it will never be changed. So it seems there is no gain in creating a second table. Am I right?

Comment: Never is a long time.

Comment: The table is a results only table. So never means never in this case. =) So again I ask, what are the benefits in creating a second table as long as there's a way to do what I initially asked?

Comment: Every time you run this query you'll have to parse that string. That's slower.  Also as @paqogomez says it's hard to believe the user types will never be updated.

Comment: I have dozens of reference tables in my database that rarely change.  I've even created a template file in my solution to make enums out of them so i can reference them in code w/o strings.  They do change tho, its rare, but they change.  New requirements come by all the time.  You can do what you want, but in 3 months when you post the question "how do I unravel my crappy architecture" you'll think of me. :)

Comment: Yes I think it's better to just use a second relational table after all. I was just hoping that my conversion from our current system to this new system could be a bit faster/easier than changing all of the code to handle a second relational table. But at least this way, my code is not tied to MSSQL only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There'e many examples of TSQL code that split separated string into "array" or table variable.

For example using this function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/961695, you can rewrite your query as:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM perm p JOIN dbo.splitstring('50,40,30') s
ON p.user_type = s.name
```

(and avoid dynamic SQL as well)

Comment: It's not letting me create the function. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express. Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the function like `u.type IN (dbo.splitstring(p.user_type))` but I should've been using it like `u.type IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring(p.user_type))`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. But I still recommend using JOIN instead of IN

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the way that works with what you have now (horrible) and the right way to do it (as @paqogomez suggested). This way involves abusing `PARSENAME`, and only works with SQL Server and only if perm.user_type has 4 or fewer user types. There's another way that doesn't have the limit of 4--it involves abusing SQL Server's XML parsing--but it's more complex and slower so I won't show that one:

I also assume you just want to list the rows in Perm for a specific user, and the `[user]` table has `id` as it primary key:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [user] u
JOIN perm p ON u.type IN (
    CAST((PARSENAME(REPLACE(p.user_type,',','.'),1)) AS INT),
    CAST((PARSENAME(REPLACE(p.user_type,',','.'),2)) AS INT),
    CAST((PARSENAME(REPLACE(p.user_type,',','.'),3)) AS INT),
    CAST((PARSENAME(REPLACE(p.user_type,',','.'),4)) AS INT)
)
WHERE u.id = ?
```

The better way is the paqogomez way, where you use a relation table to store the user types for Perm (assumes the primary key for Perm is `id`:

```
Perm_User_Type
  Perm_id -> Perm.id
  User_type -> [user].type
```

Then the much more efficient query would look like this:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [user] u
JOIN Perm_User_Type put ON u.type = put.User_type
JOIN perm p ON put.Perm_id = p.id
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Of course there would be no limit on the number of user types in this case.

Comment: Very creative. However, there are more than 4 user types. There can be an infinite number of them.

Comment: There's no limit on the user types, just a limit on the number of user types a given entry in the Perm table can have. If a given entry in the Perm table can have more than 4 user types associated with it, you'll have to abuse the XML parsing features instead. That's a lot more complex. Do I really have to look it up (I can't remember off the top of my head) or will you **please** do it the right way?

Comment: Or, you simply make sure that no Perm row has more than 4 users associated with it. At this point the schema/data is no masterpiece anyway.  :P

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this without dynamic SQL. Something like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = '
SELECT p.*
FROM perm p
JOIN [user] u ON u.type IN (''' + p.user_type + ''')'

exec sp_ExecuteSql @sql
```

Comment: This won't work. `p.user_type` is a string that has: `'50,40,30'` inside, and you'll need the dynamic SQL to be: `'50','40','30'`, with single quotes between the commas

Comment: Not sure who downvoted, as it's a pretty good solution.  There's at least one way that was pointed out to avoid the dynamic SQL, but it's not like this is a 600 line query where stuff can go wrong relatively easily.